# Работа со справочниками

Tags: 1с

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой при работе со справочниками.
Есть задание - Показать все наименования товаров, у которых закупочная цена последней доставки выше средней закупочной цены за все время.
Знаю как это сделать на c#, но на 1с совсем не получается. В идеале, конечно, помочь кодом на задание, но и описать в общих чертах, что нужно тоже неплохо. 
[yadi.sk/d/dmH-HibgoCyApA](http://yadi.sk/d/dmH-HibgoCyApA) - конфигурация
Всем чистого кода :-)

Comment: В чем конкретно вы видите проблему?

Comment: Не знаю как перебрать все элементы, которые находятся в справочнике. Так же непонятно как перебрать данные, которые находятся в табличной части справочника

Answer (score 0):

Только на справочниках ты эту задачу не сделаешь, т.к. тебе необходимо хранить историю цен, поэтому:

1. Цены номенклатуры должны быть в регистре сведений. У регистра сведений есть такая функция, как "Срез последних". Суть: на вход подаёшь измерения (номенклатура и вид цены), а на выходе будет ресурс (значение цены).
2. По поводу задания: делаешь запрос. Выбираешь ВСЮ номенклатуру, помещаешь во временную таблицу. С помощью этих данных (так же запросом) находишь среднюю цену за всё время (второй пакет запроса) и с помощью среза последних регистра сведений "Цены номенклатуры" находишь последнюю (третий пакет запроса). После этого идёт итоговый пакет запроса, где соединяешь второй и третий пакет по номенклатуре и в условие ставишь, где цена за всё время меньше, чем цена последней поставки (ну или как тебе надо)